# "Лазал" или "лазил"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "лазал" или "лазил"? Вроде бы, первый вариант вернее, но так никто не говорит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современная норма допускает оба варианта.
Более страя литературная норма - лазить.
Лазать до недавнего времени считалась разговорной, но некоторые современные словари (Лопатин, например) дают этот вариант как равноправный.

Но тут есть сложность. У этих вариантов разные, не взаимозаменяемые, личные формы, их нельзя путать:

**лазить, лажу, лазишь, лазит, лазим;пов. лазь [не лазию, лазиешь]  

лазать, лазаю, лазаешь, лазает, лазаем;пов. лазай (разг. к лазить)**
(Зарва, "Русское словесное ударение")